# If a $30~cm$ wheel rotates by $32^\circ$, through what angle does a $12~cm$ wheel rotate?

Tags: trigonometry

A tricycle has a front wheel that is $30~cm$ in diameter and two rear wheels each with a diameter of $12~cm$. If the front wheel rotates an angle of $32^\circ$, through how many degrees does each rear wheel rotate, to the nearest tenth of a degree?

Comment: what has been tried to solve it ?

Comment: Hint: Since the wheels grip the ground, the length of the arcs the front and back wheels rotate through are equal. Now equate these to find the answer.

Comment: I don't even know where to start. I tried arc length equation, but that got me nowhere and now I'm stuck.

Comment: the arcs are on a circle no ?

Comment: yes they are. ok so I determined the arc length of the larger wheel: 8.37cm, now do I use that to find the angle of the small circles?

Comment: I simply used the ratio of the radii in my head to come to my answer using a formula from geometry.

Comment: The question is not quite complete. It becomes quite interesting if the trike goes in a bent. Then the input data is not yet sufficient. Nothing is said about the trajectory. The simplest assumption is that the trike goes straight.

Comment: is the answer 1.40 rads?

Comment: I just used 30/12=5/2 =2.5;  2.5*32 degrees =80 degrees.  but I'm probably wrong on my usage.

Comment: The usual procedure for homework here is that others give you hints and you write the answer yourself. The others can correct you if you went wrong.

Comment: @Tobias so I should just delete my comments then ?

Comment: Your 1.4 rad are quite right. But, the questioner wants the answer in degree...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee As I stated before helping comments are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the front wheel does $12$ revolutions, then  the rear wheels will do $30$ revolutions.

So in general the rear wheels go $\dfrac{30}{12}$ times the angle that the front wheel goes.

The calculation is then $\dfrac{30}{12} \times 32^\circ = 80.0^\circ$

Comment: Thank you, you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Bigger wheel rolls $$\frac{32^\circ}{360^\circ}\cdot 2\pi\cdot30\text{cm}$$

Smaller wheel rolls

$$\frac{x}{360^\circ}\cdot 2\pi \cdot 12\text{cm}$$

Since they roll the same distance we get

$$x=\frac{30\text{cm}}{12\text{cm}}\cdot 32^\circ=80^\circ$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  the length of an arc of a circle is the radius of the circle times the central angle (in radians), so in your problems the angles are in the inverse ratio to the radii